# Google Chart with slicer returns: One or more participants failed to draw()×

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm a little bit lost with [Google Charts's DateRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#daterangefilter). Upon drawing the dashboard, I'm getting the error message "One or more participants failed to draw()×". I'm not quite sure why this is happening, but my hunch says it is due to the Date object. The jsonHRData date rows looks like "Date {Sat Feb 15 2014 15:17:33 GMT+0100 (CET)}". Initially my JSON returned ISO formatted dates, which I converted to the JavaScript date format using [this approach](http://erraticdev.blogspot.be/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html).

Note that the slicer itself is drawn, but not the ColumnChart itself. Every time I slice, the error message repeats itself.

```
function drawDashboard() {
  var jsonHRData = $.ajax({
      url: "heartrate.json",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false,
      converters: {
        "text json": function (data) {
            return $.parseJSON(data, true);
        }
       },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       }
      }).responseJSON;

  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
 var dateRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel' : 'Date'

    }
});

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var HRdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonHRData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var heartrateChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'heartrate_container',
    'options': {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 240,
        'colors': '#f3b49f'
    }
});

// Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'heartrateChart',
// so that the column chart will only display entries that are let through
// given the chosen slider range.
dashboard.bind(dateRangeSlider, heartrateChart);

// Draw the dasbhoard
dashboard.draw(HRdata);
}
```

My JSON looks as follows:

```
{"cols":[{"id":"Date","label":"Date","type":"date"},{"id":"Average Heartrate","label":"Average Heartrate","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2014-02-15T14:17:33Z"},{"v":158.4}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-02-13T18:32:33Z"},{"v":170.7}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-02-10T18:59:20Z"},{"v":161.7}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-02-08T14:05:21Z"},{"v":171.1}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-02-06T18:16:06Z"},{"v":168.4}]}]}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resolution was to place my ChartWrapper DIV container (here heartrate_container) outside of the ControlWrapper filter DIV container. It seemed Google Chart API was unable to find the respective element. Placing the ChartWrapper DIV outside the filter_div, as shown in the example below would solve the issue.

```
       <div id="dashboard_div">
       <div id="filter_div"></div>   <div id="heartrate_container"></div>
       </div>
```

Hence, the below would not work:

```
       <div id="dashboard_div">
       <div id="filter_div"> <div id="heartrate_container"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: The reason for this is because the API overwrites the contents of the container divs specified for each control or chart, so when the API drew the control in `filter_div`, the `heartrate_container` div was removed from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks asgallant. This makes sense!

Comment: It is actually [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls), section `1. Create An HTML Skeleton For Your Dashboard`.